# Prime decomposition for knots in manifolds

Tags: knot-theory

A knot in S^3 is uniquely decomposed into a connected sum of prime knots. What is known for knots in other three-manifolds?

Comment: What definition of connect-sum do you want to use?  I suppose the most natural one would be to take connect-sum of the ambient manifolds along common 3-balls that intersect the knots in unknotted arcs. Is that what you're interested in? 

Comment: Perhaps that will work. But even better to say: this raises another question, namely what all possible definitions of connected sum(s) are!

Comment: @Ryan- I would ask also whether there is a little discs operad action in such a context. What would happen with your work with Fred Cohen for long knots in other 3-manifolds?

Comment: There is a 2-cubes/discs action for "knots" in a variety of 3-manifolds but they're maybe not what most people would like to call knots.  Things like self-embeddings of $\mathbb{R}\times \Sigma$ in itself with support contained in $[-1,1]\times \Sigma$ where $\Sigma$ is a compact 2-manifold.  Presumably there's more global algebraic structure lurking in the background for general knots in 3-manifolds but I haven't found a strong formalism for it. 

Answer (score 9):

This was addressed in Miyazaki, [Conjugation and the prime decomposition of knots in closed, oriented 3-manifolds](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-313-02/S0002-9947-1989-0997679-2/S0002-9947-1989-0997679-2.pdf), using the definition of connected sum suggested by Ryan Budney in the comments.

The main results are that a prime decomposition of K exists iff a meridian of K is not null-homotopic in the complement of K, and if a prime decomposition of K does not contain a particular knot R in S<sup>1</sup>×S<sup>2</sup> then it is the unique decomposition of K, whereas knots with this summand R can admit several prime decompositions.